# How to make unix service see environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, init-script, services

I have set my environment variable using `/etc/profile`:

```
export VAR=/home/userhome
```

Then if I do `echo $VAR` it shows `/home/userhome`

But when I put reference to this variable into the `/etc/init.d/servicename` file, it cannot find this variable. When I run `service servicename status` using `/etc/init.d/servicename` file with following content:

```
case "$1" in
status)    
    cd $VAR/dir
    ;;
esac
```

it says `/dir: No such file or directory`

But it works if I run `/etc/init.d/servicename status` instead of `service servicename status`

How can I make unix service see environment variables?

Comment: Note that invoking the System 5 `rc` script directly _also_ does not operate that way on systemd operating systems, as all invocations of the script are turned into invocations of `systemctl` by a hidden hook.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The problem is `service` strips all environment variables but `TERM`, `PATH` and `LANG` which is a good thing. If you are executing the script directly nothing removes the environment variables so everything works.

You don't want to rely on external environment variables because at startup the environment variable probably isn't present and your init system probably won't set it anyway.

If you still want to rely on such variables, source a file and read the variables from it, e.g. create `/etc/default/servicename` with the content:

```
VAR=value
```

and source it from your init script, e.g:

```
[ -f /etc/default/service-name ] && . /etc/default/service-name

if [ -z "$VAR" ] ;  then
  echo "VAR is not set, please set it in /etc/default/service-name" >&2
  exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
status)    
    cd "$VAR"/dir
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. For other Linux newbies, here's the cryptic Bash stuff. `[ ... ]` is a shorthand for a conditional test; see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99186/72349). `-f` is an `if` argument to check if file exists. `&&` is a short-circuit operator:  only do the second command if the first exits with 0. `.` source or dot operator:  read and execute commands from the filename argument. `-z` is an `if` argument to check for a zero-length string.  `>&2` send output to stderr. See also [Introduction to if](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Comment: @MarkBerry `-f` is part of `[`, not `if`.

Comment: @ChrisDown, thanks. So "`[ ... ]` is a shorthand for a conditional `test` command; see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99186/72349). `-f` is a `test` argument to check if a file exists."

Comment: @MarkBerry Correct. You can think of `[` (or `test`) as just another command -- all `if` does is take some action based on exit status.

Comment: I've run into a situation similar to this, but I don't need `$VAR` to be in the init script, I need it to be available to a different program 2 or 3 calls *downstream* of the init script. Eg. init script calls start-stop-daemon which calls Program 1 (Java) which calls Program 2 which needs `$VAR`. I tried the trick in this answer but it doesn't seem to work in my situation. How can I ensure that `$VAR` will be available to Program 2?

Comment: Sorry but, are you sure that this example really works? I have seen comments in other post like "a child process cannot change environment variables" and I have tested something like this example, and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I needed a `RAILS_ENV` that was set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`: `export RAILS_ENV=staging`. I added `$(grep RAILS_ENV /etc/bash.bashrc)` and that made the variable available to the script. I did it this way so i didn't have to include the rest of the file.

Comment: neat arcane trick, but this is the only thing that worked in my own similar scenario :/

Answer (score 1):

One **ugly** solution that will also work:

```
function exec() {
    args=( $@ )
    command=${args[0]}
    dummy=${args[1]}
    whoami=`whoami`
    if [ -z "$dummy" ]; then
        me=`basename $0`
        runuser -l ${whoami} -c "bash /etc/init.d/${me} ${command} dummy"
    else
       printenv
   fi
}

case $1 in
    status)
        status
        ;;
    start|stop|kill|restart)
        exec $*
        ;;
    *)
        usage
esac
```