# bashscript to detect right arrow key being pressed

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why does this always detect as true, even if the keycode is not right-arrow-key?

```
stty_state=`stty -g`
stty raw; stty -echo
keycode=`dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null`
stty "$stty_state"  

echo $keycode

if [ "$keycode"=39 ]; then
echo "Right Arrow Key Pressed!"
fi
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842896/bash-scripting-read-single-keystroke-including-special-keys-enter-and-space

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You (likely) read first out of two+ bytes. `$keycode` in your script would be ESC when arrow key is pressed.

Arrow keys can be:

```
\x1b + some value
```

It always evaluates to true because of missing spaces in conditional expression.

***Edit: an update on that statement.***

Your `if` operates on the exit status of the `[` command. The `[` command is equivalent to `test`. The fact that it is a *command* is a very important fact. As a command it require spaces between arguments. The `[` command is further special in that it require `]` as last argument.

```
[ EXPRESSION ]
```

The command exits with the status determined by EXPRESSION. 1 or 0, *true* or *false*.

It is *not* an exotic way to write parenthesis. In other words it is *not* part of the `if` syntax as for example in C:

```
if (x == 39)
```

By:

```
if [ "$keycode"=39 ]; then
```

you issue:

```
[ "$keycode"=39 ]
```

which expands to

```
[ \x1b=39 ]
```

here `\x1b=39` is read as *one* argument. When `test` or `[` is given *one* argument it exits with false *only if* EXPRESSION is null – which is is never going to be. Even if `$keycode` was empty, it would result in `=39` (which is not null / empty).

Another way to look at it is that you say:

```
if 0 ; then # When _command_ exit with 0.
if 1 ; then # When _command_ exit with 1.
```

Read these questions and answers for more details – as well as discussion on `[` vs `[[`:

- [using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)
- [What do square brackets mean without the "if" on the left?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left)

In that regard you could also research back ticks `` vs `$( )`

---

***Multibyte escape sequence with arrow keys:***

As mentioned at the top: *You (likely) read first out of two+ bytes. `$keycode` in your script would be ESC when arrow key is pressed.*

Arrow and other special keys result in [*escape sequences*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) to be sent to the system. The [*ESC* byte](http://www.asciitable.com/) signals that *"here comes some bytes that should be interpreted differently"*. As for arrow keys that would be the ASCII `[` followed by ASCII `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

In other words you have to parse three bytes when dealing with arrow keys.

You could try something in the direction of this to check:

```
{   stty_state=$(stty -g)
    stty raw isig -echo
    keycode=$(dd bs=8 conv=sync count=1)
    stty "$stty_state"
} </dev/tty 2>/dev/null
printf %s "$keycode" | xxd
```

Yield:

```
HEX        ASCII
1b 5b 41   .[A # Up arrow
1b 5b 42   .[B # Down arrow
1b 5b 43   .[C # Right arrow
1b 5b 44   .[D # Left arrow
 |  |  |
 |  |  +------ ASCII A, B, C and D
 |  +--------- ASCII [
 +------------ ASCII ESC
```

Not sure how portable this is, but have earlier played around with code like this for catching arrow keys. Press `q` to quit:

```
while read -rsn1 ui; do
    case "$ui" in
    $'\x1b')    # Handle ESC sequence.
        # Flush read. We account for sequences for Fx keys as
        # well. 6 should suffice far more then enough.
        read -rsn1 -t 0.1 tmp
        if [[ "$tmp" == "[" ]]; then
            read -rsn1 -t 0.1 tmp
            case "$tmp" in
            "A") printf "Up\n";;
            "B") printf "Down\n";;
            "C") printf "Right\n";;
            "D") printf "Left\n";;
            esac
        fi
        # Flush "stdin" with 0.1  sec timeout.
        read -rsn5 -t 0.1
        ;;
    # Other one byte (char) cases. Here only quit.
    q) break;;
    esac
done
```

(As a minor note you also (intend to) test against decimal 39 – which looks like a mixup between decimal and hexadecimal. First byte in an escape sequence is [ASCII value ESC](http://www.asciitable.com/), which is *decimal* 27 and hexadecimal `0x1b`, while *decimal* 39 is hexadecimal `0x27`.)

Comment: The first problem in the question is that there are no spaces surrounding the `=` sign in the test, so it's parsed simply as a non-empty string and hence is true. The fact that arrow keys are multiple bytes is a separate issue.

Comment: Hmm, that sentence doesn't have much context as-is, I read over that as I thought that was part of the explanation of multi-byte sequences which I knew already.

Comment: @wurtel: Yes. To vague I guess. Find that once one explain `[` is a builtin *command* people grasp why spaces are important much more quickly. (It is not simply a weird way of bash to use brackets instead of parenthesis.) Have to run out now. Update once back.