# Making environment variables available for downstream processes started within an init.d script

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, init.d, amazon-ec2, upstart

This questions stems from @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables#comment375681_44378).

How do I make `export` environment variables set within an init.d script available to downstream processes started within that same init.d script?

In more detail, I am on an Amazon EC2 instance and using an init.d script to control my `node`.js server that is in turn controlled by `nodemon` which monitors for file changes and restarts `node` as needed. So in short, my init.d script starts `nodemon` which then starts `node`. Environment variables set with `export` within the init.d script seem to be available to `nodemon`, but unavailable to `node`. How do I make these environment variables available to `node` as well?

Currently, only init.d is available in my Amazon EC2 instance so is this even possible with init.d scripts, and if not, is this possible with upstart or preferably systemd?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nodemon, but it sounds to me like nodemon is deciding which variables to pass on to its children processes; if you've exported them from the init script, you now need to focus on nodemon.

Comment: In my particular situation, you are right; `nodemon` should be handling the environment variables and not the init.d script itself. For this reason and others, I have switched to `pm2` which is far better than `nodemon` at handling environment variables.

Comment: Still though, I think this is a valuable question that if answered, could help a few out there that were in a similar position as myself. If there is really no solution specific to the question asked, please post your comment @JeffSchaller as an answer, so that I may mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad you found another way that works. No idea how to fix the issue, but there is an alternative when bash or another shell won't pass variables the way you need it to. You can write your data to files either as pure data you can read or as bash/shell code you  source (if it doesn't open security holes) in subsequent scripts. The trick is using process ID or something similar in the file names so that each script gets the right file when multiple instances are running. If you put them all in a directory under /tmp, you can delete the whole thing when done instead of tracking each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend switching to a systemd based Linux distro, like Fedora or Ubuntu 16.04. `systemd` can easily pass environment variables to your process AND it can handle automatically restarting your process it fails as well as starting it at boot. Logging is also nicely handled by systemd`s journald.  There's also not the overhead of installing or running anything else, since systemd is part of of the OS distribution.

Here's an example of setting two environment environment variable with systemd in a unit file:

```
Environment="ONE=one" 'TWO=two two'
```

Full docs are [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines).

Your problem was partly one of complexity, as both the init system and the process manager handled passing environment variables. With systemd as both the init system and the process manager, a layer of complexity is removed.

Comment: I started to edit your answer, but perhaps it is better if someone more experienced like yourself add a tiny how-to on **systemd environment directives** and **conf drop-ins**? If you do, I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I added example syntax for setting systemd environment variables. I'm not sure about the "conf drop-ins" you are referring to. That's not a term I used. What's a "conf drop-in" ?

Comment: Sorry, _conf drop-ins_ may be specific to CoreOS only. What I was trying to refer to was the EnvironmentFIle directive. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using Environment directive in the systemd service itself as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291184/173615), another option is the EnvironmentFile directive.

Please note that I am no expert in this area (obviously, I am the author of this question); I am only summarizing to the best of my ability the [Fedora Wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files). Feel free to edit/correct me.

## EnvironmentFile directive

Create a file containing new-line-separated variable assignments:

```
# myservice.env
ENV1=value1
ENV2=value2
```

Then, in your service unit file, use the EnvironmentFile directive:

```
[Service]
...
EnvironmentFile=-/path/to/myservice.env
...
```

Within your unit file, use `${ENV1}` and `$ENV1` to refer to the variables set within *myservice.env*.

The "-" on the `EnvironmentFile=` line ensures that no error messages is generated if the environment file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In virtualized environments like AWS EC2 you may want to leverage `/etc/environment`

```
[Service]
...
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
...
```