# launching bourne shell script with $USR env

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, bourne-shell

I am running a bourne shell script from a service script.

When I check `$env` from my `#!/bin/sh` script started by script the user is ROOT and path is [/]

Is there a way to pass the env of the logged in user to the shell script from the service?

Is there some decent way to handle it so that I can get the currently logged in user and not an empty env with root user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make unix service see environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables)

Comment: See this also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot

Comment: These aren't startup scripts; the system will need to be up, running and a user needs to be logged in before these scripts will ever be called.